# re-write column's values to obtain previous line's value if exceed number 1

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I have a file containing the following list of numbers:

```
0.1131492
0.1231466
0.1327564
0.1017683
5.4356130
0.1360532
5.4258129
0.1433982
0.1124752
.
.
.
```

I would like to re-write this list of numbers if a line contains a value which is greater than 1.0000 then obtain previous line's number/value, such as:

```
0.1131492
0.1231466
0.1327564
0.1017683
0.1017683
0.1360532
0.1360532
0.1433982
0.1124752
.
.
.
```

Comment: What is the desired output if the _first_ line already exceeds 1?

Comment: should be 0.1 if first line is >1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$0>1 { $0=NR==1?0.1:prev }{ prev=$0; print }' file
```

If the current line is greater `1`, assign `0.1` to the current line if the line number is `1` or the previous value otherwise.
Then assign the current line to the `prev` variable and print the current line.